# vertical alignment of 3 columns with different content

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I'm using the linguistic [**avm**](http://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/) library along with **tikz** and I am trying to put a `\leftrightarrow` vertically centered between the attribute-value matrix and the **tikz** image.

[image: I am not succeeding]

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.40\linewidth}
    \vspace{10pt}
        \begin{avm}
            [{} attra & 1 \\
                attrb & 2 \\
                attrc & 3 \[\]]
    \end{avm} 
\end{minipage} \qquad
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.1\linewidth}
        \centering $\leftrightarrow $
\end{minipage}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.40\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,fill=green,minimum height=30.00pt,minimum width=150.00pt] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Too tired for a proper answer, but change the optional argument of the minipages from `t`(op) to `c`(enter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Torbjørn T.** mentioned in his comment, change the `t` (top) vertical alignment option to `c` (center) for the `minipage`s. I also did some minor changes: increased the width of the third `minipage` to accommodate the circle, and some others:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.40\linewidth}
  \begin{avm}
  \[{} attra & 1 \\
  attrb & 2 \\
  attrc & 3 \[\] \]
  \end{avm} 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{.1\linewidth}
  \centering\strut$\leftrightarrow$
\end{minipage}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.44\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,fill=green,minimum height=30.00pt,minimum width=150.00pt] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I made this answer CW since the credit goes not to me but to **Torbjørn T.**.